# eclipse plugin to generate package and class diagram

Tags: eclipse

I wrote classes and packages in eclipse ,and now i want to visually see its structure. Is there a tool that can generate UML class and package diagram from eclipse itselft without having to manually draw it in another tool?

Answer (score 4):

Try Object Aid :
http://www.objectaid.com/class-diagram

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the documentation with Doxygen. You'll need the [eclipse doxygen plugin](http://home.gna.org/eclox/). Create and edit your doxyfile to **generate the diagrams** you need and open the doc in Eclipse's browser to browse through the doc and **see your class diagram**.

You will need to have doxygen and graphviz installed.

Comment: this is not what i want. I clearly stated that i want a uml representation of the classes that i have written.

Comment: Tought JAVADOC produces the diagram, use doxygen instead with the eclipse doxygen plugin : http://home.gna.org/eclox/

Comment: I perfectly understand but you don't. I'm telling you to use doxygen to generate YOUR CLASS DIAGRAM. So don't get mad at me when I'm offering you help.

Answer (score 0):

[green.sourceforge.net/](http://green.sourceforge.net/) You can use green to create a UML class diagram from code, or to generate code by drawing a class diagram.

[UML2](http://www.vogella.de/articles/UML/article.html)
This article gives a short overview of UML2 and explains the usage of the Eclipse UML2 Tools for modeling UML 2 diagrams.

[Omondo](http://www.ejb3.org/product.html)